# Merge 'non-market' to 'side-loading'

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

Questions tagged [non-market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-market) (× 6) are all about [side-loading](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/side-loading) (× 17), some even carry this second tag additionally. Hence my proposal:

- merge 'non-market' into 'side-loading'
- optionally make the former a synonym to the latter, alternatively simply let it die

Comment: Where would devices like the Kindle Fire that have an alternate app-store installed (ie not THE Market) fit in here (most Samsung devices also have both the Play Store and a separate Samsung Store app)? They're "non-market", but not "side-loading"?

Comment: Have you checked whether you can use the non-market markets with "unknown sources" disabled? (I have no such devices, so I cannot check). And as written: all questions tagged non-market are about side-loading. So simply spoken, I could also go and re-tag them, and let the non-market tag die (why didn't I think about that before? ;) -- unless somebody uses it for the reason you mentioned, of course...

Comment: @GAThrawn: We do have the [alternative-markets tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-markets) as well. That seems like it may actually be better than "non-market" just because it's a bit more focused. Would that alleviate your concerns?

Comment: Not to forget the [amazone-appstore](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-appstore) tag concerning the Kindle.

Comment: @eldarerathis fair enough, alternative markets seems good to me. My only remaining concern is more of a nit-pick really. That "non-market" is an adjective describing an app, and side-loading is a verb describing something you'd do with your device. Could there be people who just want to know how to side-load apps on their device, as well as people who are interested in finding other market-places, or are gaining their apps direct from the developer. Are they necessarily going to be asking the same questions?

Comment: If they're looking for "other market-places", 'alternative-markets' would describe this best. If they want apps direct from the developer, they are looking for 'apk'. If they simply want to know how side-loading works, there's 'side-loading'. Do you want to keep 'non-market' as "third source" next to 'google-play-store' and 'alternative-markets'? I can see this would make sense (and we could have the tag-wiki pointing this out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No:** We want to keep [non-market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-market) as "app source" next to [alternative-markets](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-markets), [amazon-appstore](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-appstore), and [google-play-store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-store). Let's make this clear in the tag wiki.

Comment: I've meanwhile setup the 'non-market' tag wiki accordingly. Yes, I switched positions to support GAThrawn's arguments -- and I thing this is the best way. So if a mod wants to mark the question whatever (declined would match in this case, I think), please do :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes:** Let's merge the two, as it very likely covers the same questions/topics. The "Kindle Fire" mentioned by GAThrawn would be covered by [amazon-appstore](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-appstore) already, and other markets are covered by [alternative-markets](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-markets).